# using wireshark to figure out type of VNIC

Tags: networking, wireshark, ethernet

I've been asked in a assignment to analyze a packet trace and determine what kind of VNIC the user has on his or her machine. I'm finding this to be quite difficult however; I'm not quite sure what to look for. I'd appreciate getting pointed in the right direction. I mean whether the connection is through ethernet or a wireless 802.11 card

Comment: Do you already have the trace file or do you need to run a capture first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the capture file with you already then open the file with wireshark, and on the display filter type "wlan", then click Apply to filter out 802.11 packets. The display filter expression for ethernet is "eth". If there are any packets on display after you apply the display filter, then there were packets that used the protocol. You can look into the packets with Wireshark to see the ethernet II or 802.11 header.

You can download some sample captures of 802.11 and Ethernet II from http://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the manufacturer of the Ethernet/WLAN card? The first 6 bytes of the Ethernet address are called the Organization Unique Identifier, and you can look them up here:

http://standards.ieee.org/regauth/oui/index.shtml

Comment: No, sorry to not be clear. I meant whether the connection is through ethernet or a wireless 802.11 card

Comment: I don't think that can be determined from the packet contents. I think WiFi frames are the same as Ethernet.

Comment: @Barmar WiFi is 802.11 and Ethernet is 802.3